# Call to undefined method error in Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

My application was ok until I changed migrations and update composer. Now it returns an error like this:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException 
Call to undefined method Package::with()
```

The Package model was ok before update process. I updated the system yesterday and now almost every modal returns error like above. What happened and what is wrong with new composer?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a dev version in your composer.json file? Did you list all the facades correctly in the app.php files in all your environments? Did you try a fresh `composer dump-autoload`? Did you try a new `composer update` to see if the bug has been fixed by now?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the problem. Somehow php artisan migration:make command has created migrations with the same name of modals. I changed the class names of migrations and it works now.